# How to get Salesforce UserId using REST API

Tags: rest-api, api, user-record

In order to create opportunities thanks to the REST API, I need to get a few object ids.

Is there any way to get a User's Salesforce Id using the REST API ?

I managed to get user details using the following API route but the thing is that the third part software which is going to create the opportunity doesn't know the Salesforce UserId.

> /services/data/vX.XX/sobjects/User/UserId

Other fields (like username for example) doesn't seem to be queryable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can I clarify which user's Id you want to get?

Comment: [UserInfo](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/user/0052w00000FsKKdAAN***

where 0052w00000FsKKdAAN is the user id to get all the information about user

If your external system want only certain fields about a user in someway related to opportunity (For Eg owner), you can make use of query service as below:
***/services/data/v58.0/query?q=Select Id,Owner.Name,Owner.Id,Owner.Username from opportunity where Id='xxxxx'***

Comment: Hi,

As mentionned, the main issue is that the third part software doesn't know the user's Salesforce Id. Anyway, thanks to your comment I tried to use the query service using the username (which is the user's email address in this case) to get the id :

/services/data/v58.0/query?q=Select Id from user where Username='xxx@xxx.com'

And it works :)

Thank you !

Comment: Happy that it helped. Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/services/data/v58.0/` (or any supported version), which will include, as part of the response, your identity URL:

```
{
  "tooling" : "/services/data/v58.0/tooling",
  "metadata" : "/services/data/v58.0/metadata",
...
  "identity" : "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D500000000000AAA/005500000000000AAA",
...
}
```

Where `00D500000000000AAA` is the Org ID, `005500000000000AAA` is the User ID for the logged in user.

From there, using `/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/User/005500000000000AAA` will give you all the primary user details, and the identity URL will return a Chatter-like response that includes basic data like name, email, and address.